# Django filter all assigned foreing keys

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Hello I would like to ask how to filter all assigned ForeignKeys of the object. My models looks like:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=250)

class VirtualProject(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person)

class Hours(models.Model):
    hours = models.FloatField()
    assigned_virtual_project = ForeignKey(VirtualProject)
    date = models.DateField()
```

I am sending GET request with owner and dateRange parameters and I would like to filter all virtual projects assigned to the owner (this is no issue, I can get this) AND also get all hours objects assigned to the virtual projects and sum all hours in specified date range. How I can do that? For frontend I am using React, so I am using django rest framework.
What I got so far in views:

```
class GetDataView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
       owner = self.request.query_params.get('owner')
       dateRange = self.request.query_params.get('dateRange')

       queryset = VirtualProject.objects.filter(owner=owner)
       return queryset
```

EDIT:

Serializers.py:

```
class VirtualProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
         class Meta:
             model = VirtualProject
             fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: you want response of API have sum all hours of each `VirtualProject`? or sum all hours of all `VirtualProject` match queryset?

Comment: I would like response of all hours of each VirtualProject based on owner field

Comment: Can you add DataSerializer code in your question ? @pipikej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) in your serializer, associated with a sum aggregate query.

```py
from django.db.models import Sum
from models import Hours

class VirtualProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
         hours = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

         class Meta:
             model = VirtualProject
             fields = '__all__'

         def get_hours(self, obj):
             qs = Hours.objects.filter(assigned_virtual_project=obj).aggregate(Sum(hours))
             return qs
```

Note that this will be read-only, which I believe is what you want anyway.

Comment: With this I receive hours is not defined from the aggregate(Sum(hours)). I tred to edit it to: Sum('hours'). but I receive KeyError: 'hours_sum'

Comment: When I changed `return qs[hours_sum]` to `return qs` then it is working. It adds this `"hours": {
            "hours__sum": value
        },` to the API.

Comment: Oh ok, maybe adding [hours_sum] to the above line is what would work, but i did not try it. I edit my answer with what you provided.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Also I would like to ask if there is any way to pass parameters from GET request to the serializer, because I do not want to sum all hours, but only from specified month as I am sending the dateRange? I tried to filter in the views but it did not work very well. Thank you.

Comment: @pipikej Yes it's possible to pass the request object to the serializer via context. I think a ModelViewSet already includes it by default, so wherever you need in your serializer you can access query params through `self.context["request"].query_params["month"]` if your url is something like url/endpoint?month=January. If that explanation is not enough, just open another question.

Comment: This is enough, you are the best!